# I want to build a nested serializer to display order with product and each product showing its individual value. I have my code below

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get a nested serializer with individual value displayed with particular product but i am getting all the values in a single product.
i dont kow what to do there is some mistake in my code i cant figure out where.
please help me out.
this is my code

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='orders', 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    paid_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at',]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_total_price(self):
        total = sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
    blank=True)
    glasses = models.ForeignKey(Glasses, related_name='glass', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity


class Power(models.Model):
    frame = models.ForeignKey(OrderItem, related_name='power', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=[('Powered', 'Powered'), ('bifocal', 'bifocal'), 
    ('Frame_only', 'Frame_only')])
    left_eye_power = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    left_eye_cylinder = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    left_eye_bifocal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    left_eye_axis = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    right_eye_power = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    right_eye_cylinder = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    right_eye_bifocal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    right_eye_axis = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

serializer.py

```
class PowerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Power
        fields = '__all__'



class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #power = serializers.RelatedField(read_only=True)
    power = PowerSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = (
            "price",
            "glasses",
            "power",
            "quantity",
        )



class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
            "address",
            "zipcode",
            "place",
            "phone",
            "items",
        )
```

views.py

```
class OrderListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
```

output i got:

```
{
 "count": 1,
 "next": null,
 "previous": null,
 "results": [
     {
         "id": 1,
         "first_name": "priyank",
         "last_name": "nair",
         "email": "priyankshashinair@gmail.com",
         "address": "1/A 401",
         "zipcode": "400102",
         "place": "Mumbai",
         "phone": "9833437879",
         "items": [
             {
                 "price": "234.00",
                 "glasses": 1,
                 "power": [
                     {
                         "id": 1,
                         "type": "Powered",
                         "left_eye_power": "0.16",
                         "left_eye_cylinder": "0.14",
                         "left_eye_bifocal": "0.16",
                         "left_eye_axis": "0.13",
                         "right_eye_power": "0.14",
                         "right_eye_cylinder": "0.15",
                         "right_eye_bifocal": "0.14",
                         "right_eye_axis": "0.19",
                         "frame": 1
                     },
                     {
                         "id": 2,
                         "type": "Frame_only",
                         "left_eye_power": null,
                         "left_eye_cylinder": null,
                         "left_eye_bifocal": null,
                         "left_eye_axis": null,
                         "right_eye_power": null,
                         "right_eye_cylinder": null,
                         "right_eye_bifocal": null,
                         "right_eye_axis": null,
                         "frame": 1
                     }
                 ],
                 "quantity": 1
             },
             {
                 "price": "234.00",
                 "glasses": 2,
                 "power": [],
                 "quantity": 2
             }
         ]
     }
 ]
 }
```

Output i want:

```
{
"count": 1,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "priyank",
        "last_name": "nair",
        "email": "priyankshashinair@gmail.com",
        "address": "1/A 401",
        "zipcode": "400102",
        "place": "Mumbai",
        "phone": "9833437879",
        "items": [
            {
                "price": "234.00",
                "glasses": 1,
                "power": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "type": "Powered",
                        "left_eye_power": "0.16",
                        "left_eye_cylinder": "0.14",
                        "left_eye_bifocal": "0.16",
                        "left_eye_axis": "0.13",
                        "right_eye_power": "0.14",
                        "right_eye_cylinder": "0.15",
                        "right_eye_bifocal": "0.14",
                        "right_eye_axis": "0.19",
                        "frame": 1
                    }
                ],
                "quantity": 1
            },
            {
                "price": "234.00",
                "glasses": 2,
                "power": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "type": "Frame_only",
                        "left_eye_power": null,
                        "left_eye_cylinder": null,
                        "left_eye_bifocal": null,
                        "left_eye_axis": null,
                        "right_eye_power": null,
                        "right_eye_cylinder": null,
                        "right_eye_bifocal": null,
                        "right_eye_axis": null,
                        "frame": 1
                    },
                 ],
                "quantity": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct, the problem is in your data - both `Power` objects clearly show `"frame": 1`, and your desired output is not possible without the second `power` having `"frame": 2`.